# Djangorestframework: is it possible to deserialize only specific fields of incoming JSON?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I need to deserialize incoming JSON.  The incoming JSON will be transformed to a Django model object called `AdvancedUser`.  An `AdvancedUser` has a one to one with a `Device` model.

When I POST my incoming JSON, I'm getting errors that say "Device field is required".

The Device field is optional in my AdvancedUser model declaration code.

How do I get rid of this error?  It's OK if no Device field is passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into using the `required=False` flag on the device field in your serializer class.